# R merge list into just one

Tags: r

given the following code:

```
dataset <- read.csv2("/DATASET/dataset.csv", header = FALSE)

# Create my_data
my_data <- dataset
# Convert to a tibble
library("tibble")
my_data <- as_data_frame(my_data)

A <- my_data[1:10,3]
B <- my_data[1:10,4]
n = nrow(A)
trainIndex = sample(1:n, size = round(0.7*n), replace=TRUE)
train = A[trainIndex ,]
test = B[-trainIndex ,]
```

After splitting the dataset in 70% training and 30% testing, I want to create one list "output" which contains the list "train" and after appends horizontally the list "test", in just one list.

e.g.:

```
output <- append(train,test)
```

But "output" has to be a new single list.
I have already tried:

```
output <- append(train,test)
```

but it makes two list into one and it doesn't make just one list.
Can you help me? thank you

Comment: *"I want to create one list "output" which contains the list "train" and after appends horizontally the list "test", in just one list."* I don't understand what you mean by "append horizontally". `A` and `B` are `data.frame`s not `list`s (ignoring the finer detail here that a `data.frame` is "special" `list`). Are you perhaps after `rbind`, i.e. `rbind(train, test)`? Or do you actually want to store `A` and `B` in a `list`, i.e. `list(A, B)`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to flatten the list by using `unlist` function. There is an optional parameter called `recursive` which defaults to TRUE.

```
final_output = unlist(output)
```